# Changing locale inside package function

Tags: r, function, locale

I have a function which resides inside a package, assume the function is called `foo()`. I want it to read an Excel file with Greek letters, so I change the locale to Greek. After reading in the datafile I do something with this data and the Greek characters and after that I want the locale changed back to the default value.

```
foo <- function(file, sheet){
   Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")
   data <- read.xlsx(file, sheet)
   cols_greek <- names(data)[which(apply(data, 2, function(x) grepl("α|β|σ|ε|γ|π|δ|θ|λ|χ|μ|°", x)), arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
   cols_greek <- cols_greek[!duplicated(cols_greek)]
   Sys.setlocale()
   return(cols_greek)
 }
```

Looks great... But it does not work when the code resides inside the `foo` function. The columns containing Greek characters are not returned correctly. Running the code just like this

```
   Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")
   data <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheet = "data")
   cols_greek <- names(data)[which(apply(data, 2, function(x) grepl("α|β|σ|ε|γ|π|δ|θ|λ|χ|μ|°", x)), arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
   cols_greek <- cols_greek[!duplicated(cols_greek)]
   Sys.setlocale()
   cols_greek
```

works perfectly fine and the right column names are returned. Can anyone tell me why that is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean? Are you getting an error? Your function `foo()` doesn't seem to be returning the `data` value anywhere. Also look at the `on.exit()` function for resetting the locale on function exit.

Comment: Does not work means the data is read in using the default locale, and not the Greek locale. After reading in the data I count the Greek characters and I return the counts from the function. This is just a plain example.

Comment: I adjusted my question a bit to make it more clear as why I want to do this.